# Unity fonts changed after using GNOME

Tags: unity, gnome, 14.10

I have installed GNOME on Ubuntu, and after using it for a while, I decided to switch back to Unity. But all the fonts have changed to the standard GNOME fonts and I want to change it back to the Ubuntu fonts.

Any help?

PS: The command I used to install GNOME was `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop`.

Comment: How did you install Gnome?

Comment: I used the Terminal, but I forgot the command -_-

Comment: If you execute the command `history` in Terminal it should tell you the last 500 or so commands that you have typed, so you should be able to find it in there. As it would be very useful to know the command.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Gnome creates a config file called .gtkrc-2.0 in your home directory to set the font on a per-user basis. Unity seems to use this file too and ends up using Gnome's default font even after Gnome has been uninstalled. Deleting this file seems to fix the problem:

```
rm ~/.gtkrc-2.0
```